# SQL, queries to cinema places

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2

Hi i have problem with  query  which  draw  free places and  taken seats and then  check in php  in loop i  writes  busy places  as disabled checkbox

My database Shema
[image]

I tried:

```
foreach ($FreePlaces as $item) {

foreach ($busyPlaces as $items) {


    if ($item->id_place == $items->id_place) {
        echo Html::checkboxList('items', null, [$items->id_place => $items->number_place], ['class' => 'checkbox-inline no_indent', 'id' => 'idd']);
    }
    else
    echo Html::checkboxList('items', null, [$item->id_place => $item->number_place], ['class' => 'checkbox-inline no_indent', 'id' => 'idd']);
}
```

}

but it not working...  look  picture
[image]

How mark busy place as disabled ?

```
 $freePlace= place::find()
      ->Where(['id_room' => seanse::find()->select('id_room')->
      Where(['id_seans' => $id])])->all();

    $busyplace=place::find()->where(['in', 'id_place', Reservation::find()->select('id_place')
        ->where(['id_seans' => $id])])
        ->andWhere(['id_room' => seanse::find()->select('id_room')->
        Where(['id_seans' => $id])])->all();
```

**Solution**

Jquery

```
 $( "input[name='items[]']:checked").prop("disabled", true);
```

php

```
 $selectedArray = [];
 foreach ($zajeteKrzesla as $items) {
  $selectedArray[] = $items->id_place;
}



    foreach ($WolneKrzesla as $item):?>


        echo Html::checkboxList('items', $selectedArray, [$item->id_place => $item->number_place], ['class' => 'checkbox-inline no_indent', 'id' => 'idd']);


    <?php endforeach;
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mark busyPlace as selected when you can change your code to this (you need to appropriate filling `$selectedArray` variable):

```
foreach ($FreePlaces as $item) {

foreach ($busyPlaces as $items) {

    // $selectedArray - selection of the check boxes. 
    // This can be either a string for single selection or 
    // an array for multiple selections. 
    if ($item->id_place == $items->id_place) {
        echo Html::checkboxList('items', $selectedArray, [$items->id_place => $items->number_place], ['class' => 'checkbox-inline no_indent', 'id' => 'idd']);
    }
    else
    echo Html::checkboxList('items', null, [$item->id_place => $item->number_place], ['class' => 'checkbox-inline no_indent', 'id' => 'idd']);
}
}
```

Comment: I would like disabled  mark  busyPlace.  I update my questions.  [My query to database]

Comment: OK, I use  SelectedArray and then use  Jquery to disabled selected  checkbox ! It working. Thaks!

Comment: I'm glad that you solved your problem